# Cannot make a systemd script run

Tags: systemd

I am having a hard time making my systemd script to run in Ubuntu 16.04. Could someone help me checking if I am doing something wrong?

This is the script:

```
[Unit]
Description=TestProject

[Service]
ExecStart="java -Xmx2048m -Xms512m -jar /opt/project/target/test-dl-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar server /opt/project/src/main/resources/config/config.yml"
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And I save it to `/lib/systemd/system/` , then I run `systemctl daemon-reload` and then `systemctl enable myservice.service`

However, the output I see from `systemctl status myservice.service` is:

```
Aug 17 14:59:17 ubuntu-8gb-sfo2-01 systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/myservice.service:7] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: 
Aug 17 14:59:17 ubuntu-8gb-sfo2-01 systemd[1]: myservice.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
```

Are you guys seeing anything wrong that I am doing? Btw, I also tried to not use quotes in the ExecStart part and I get the same error.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What happens if you replace "java" by it's absolute path as the log suggests? "which java" or "whereis java" on console might show you this path.

Comment: Thanks. Now I get a different error:

Service has no ExecStart= setting, which is only allowed for RemainAfterExit=yes services. Refusing.

Comment: What about additionally dropping the quotes? I don't saw quotes in some other unit files that I checked and I don't recognize what they are needed for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The program you are starting with `ExecStart` must have full path. Find out where your `java` binary is and add that to the ExecStart.

Ex: `ExecStart=/bin/java .....`

Comment: This has been changed in recent versions of systemd.

Comment: as Umut says, this no longer helps.